# Loading Json file into redshift using copy command

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load below json file into redshift using copy command providing json path.I am not able to load the file and getting error and I understood from previous posts that it might not support ',' after end of array .Is there any way to load the file without any pre-processing?

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1111, 
        "name": "ABCD"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2222, 
        "name": "PQRS"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3333, 
        "name": "WXYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is the intention to load into a `Users` table, which would result in 3 rows of data? If so, this does not match the format that Redshift expects and it would require pre-processing.

Comment: You should be posting your table `schema` and `copy query` to get a solution on this..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently load this using `COPY`. **However,** we recently introduced the ability to query nested data with Redshift Spectrum. You can use this capability to insert the data into a Redshift table.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "users": [
    { "id": 1111,
      "name": "ABCD" },
    { "id": 2222,
      "name": "PQRS" },
    { "id": 3333,
      "name": "WXYZ" }
  ]
}

aws s3 cp ~/nested_data.json s3://my-bucket/nested_data/nested_data.json

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spectrum.nested_simple;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.nested_simple
     (users   array<struct<id:int, name:varchar(20)>> ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/nested_data/'
;

SELECT u.id
      ,u.name
FROM spectrum.nested_simple c
INNER JOIN c.users u ON true
;
--  id  | name
--------+------
-- 1111 | ABCD
-- 2222 | PQRS
-- 3333 | WXYZ
```

Recommend working through our Nested Data tutorial. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html